# Protractor-cucumber: "Sendkey" input a text "undefined" instead my text

Tags: cucumber, protractor, pageobjects

I have a test written in pageobject model with Protractor v2.5.1, Cucumberjs v0.7.0:

---------------loginpage.js---------------------

```
'use strict';

( function () {

    //var ptor;
    var navigate = function () {
        console.log("789");
        isAngularSite(false);
        browser.get("");
    };

    var login = function ( username, password ) {

        browser.driver.findElement( by.id('log')).sendKeys(username);
        browser.driver.findElement( by.id( 'pwd' ) ).sendKeys(password);
        browser.driver.findElement( by.id( 'login' ) ).click();
        browser.sleep(3000);
    };

    var LoginPage = function () {
        //var username     = browser.driver.findElement( by.id( 'log' ) );
        //var password     = browser.driver.findElement( by.id( 'pwd' ) );
        //var loginButton  = browser.driver.findElement( by.id( 'login' ) );
    };

    LoginPage.prototype.navigate = navigate();
    LoginPage.prototype.login    = login();

    module.exports = LoginPage;

} )();
```

----------------spec.js-------------------

```
'use strict';

var LoginPage      = require( './loginpage.js' );

//var HomePage       = require( '../homepage/homepage.js' );

//var chai           = require( 'chai' );
//
//var chaiAsPromised = require( 'chai-as-promised' );
//
//chai.use( chaiAsPromised );
//
//var expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function () {

    var loginPage;
    var homePage;

    this.Before( function ( callback ) {
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
        //homePage  = new HomePage();
        //isAngularSite(false);
        loginPage.navigate();
        callback();

    } );

    this.After( function ( callback ) {
        //logout
        callback();
    } );

    this.Given(/^I login using valid creadentials&/, function ( callback ) {
        loginPage.login( 'binhle', '12345678' ); //valid creadential
        callback();
    } );


};
```

When i run my test with IDE Webstorm, the console output:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 10.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" c:\Users\Dave.Le\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js config.js
Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
789
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] firefox #1 passed
```

But when i observe on browser, it just input text "undefined" for `username` and `password` fields.

My questions is:
1. Why doesn't it input my text "binhle" instead "undefined"?
2. How to see text result (FAIL in this case) for the text?

Answer (score 1):

In your page object, you are calling the `login` and `navigate` functions as you assign them:

```
LoginPage.prototype.navigate = navigate();
LoginPage.prototype.login    = login();
```

What you actually want to do is this:

```
LoginPage.prototype.navigate = navigate;
LoginPage.prototype.login    = login;
```

Or more simply:

```
var LoginPage = function LoginPage () { ... };
LoginPage.prototype.login = function (username, password) { ... };
```

Comment: Thank for your response, but when i change my code to `LoginPage.prototype.navigate = navigate;` and `LoginPage.prototype.login    = login;`, my code cannot run the command `browser.get('example.com');`. Do you know why the issues happen? Could you detail your code in simply way as your mention above? Sorry about my stupid. Thank so much.

Comment: The reason is loginpage can not init element when i call the page. so i changed the way to emplement. Thank so much.